# How to create a trigger to encrypt and decript a specific column in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, authentication, encryption, passwords

I need to create a blog and the users can authenticate with them passwords. My idea is encrypt and decrypt the password in mysql server and not with php scripts. When an user signin in platform and his password stored in an mysql table, how can I create a trigger to encrypt his password or decrypt its to verify his authentity to compare the password inserted and the password stored in mysql server?

The MySQL table is **credentials**, the columns are id, email, *password*

Comment: Not a good approach. Just create normal MySQL users and grant them `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` privileges on the tables they require - you can use `ROLE`s to help with this.

Comment: Don't store user passwords in the database ever. Don't encrypt them! You should only ever store secure hashes in the database, e.g. one generate by `password_hash()` in PHP

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. Is there a method to generate the password hash but using the database engine and not using php? So making the password clear to the database, but before the actual insertion of the record in the table is the password converted with its relative hash?

Comment: MySQL has a `PASSWORD(..)` [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html), I am not sure how safe  it is, but much safer than any custom implementation. So do not use trigger, but directly store the hashed value.  Currently the safest option we have is [slow salted hash](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/) such as PBKDF2, Argon2, Bcrypt or Scrypt